# .NET Core - Serilog - IHostBuilder does not contain a definiton of UseSerilog()

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

trying to follow this tutorial : https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/

I managed to add the Serilog to my app (.NET Core 3.1)

but I cannot modify the CreateHostBuilder function, since it **does not recognize UseSerilog() function**

I have checked for a solution, but everyone seems to use that code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;

namespace MyApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting up");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
                
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog() // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< unknown function
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

what am I missing here ?

thanks for your help

Comment: did You insall Serilog.AspNetCore - dotnet add package Serilog.AspNetCore ?

Comment: yes that was it...thanks

Comment: after updating to .net 8 I have this issue

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Answer provided by Alex Lyalka : packages were missing

```
dotnet add package Serilog.AspNetCore
```

Comment: in case of hosted service: 
dotnet add package Serilog.Extensions.Hosting

Answer (score 5):

You have to use Serilog.Extensions.Hosting package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).